# Vue & typescript: Global methods are not recognised

Tags: typescript, vue.js, mixins

I have a **Vue mixin** like so:

```
const mixin = Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        $languages: function(): object {
            return {
                en: 'english'
            }
        }
    }
}


Vue.mixin(mixin)
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(Frame)
}).$mount('#app')
```

... and I'm trying to use it in a component:

```
<template lang="pug">
    .languages
        a( v-for="language, code in $languages()" :key="code" @click="$root.$i18n.locale = code") {{ language }}&nbsp;
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        languages: function () {
            console.log(this.$languages)
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

But I get an error, saying "**Property '$languages' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance void; }, unknown, Readonly>>'**"

Curiously, if I'm just trying to use it in the `template`, it works. The language name appears. It's just the typescript code that doesn't recognise the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to augment the vue module to provide a typing for `$languages`, observe:

```
// vue-shim.d.ts

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $languages: LanguageService
  }
}
```

And a psuedo `LanguageService`

```
// language-service.d.ts

export interface LanguageService {
  $languages: () => Record<string, string>
}
```

You can read more about [augmenting Vue here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins)

Comment: Thank you very much @Ohgodwhy. Turns out, it was enough to chuck in the module declaration with '$languages: object' in the same file with my mixin and it starting working.

Comment: Correction: $languages: () => {[key: string]: string}